# HTML Table maximize-able to full screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been searching a lot to find a sample table that has a maximize button to occupy the full screen.

Imagine having a table that has this [icon](https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/controls-add-on/48/v-12-512.png) as a button somewhere and then you click it then table becomes full screen.

Bootstrap or any other version is fine :)

Comment: StackOverflow should not be treated as a code writing service. You should make some attempt at solving the problem yourself then share what you have tried, explaining the problems you have.

Comment: @JonP you are pre-judge-ing the question or me. But I believe you are right - so I am not a native english speaker - I believe when you read `Imagine having a table .... ` that would make people to think about I didn't even give it a go. 

Comment: I am not prejudging. You have provided a specification of what you want with no code. You have not provided a problem, just a specification. You will find StackOverflow more useful if you show what you have attempted explaining why it is not working as expected. I perhaps, should have phrased my second sentence as "You should show some attempt...."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pure Javascript demo:

```css
#maximizableTable{
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/mixed-vol-7/74/Untitled-1-11-08-07-17-512.png" onClick="maximizeorMinimize(this)" width="15" height="15" style="margin-left: 55%;" title="Maximize">
<table id="maximizableTable">
<tr><td>Text</td><td>Text</td></tr>
<tr><td>Text</td><td>Text</td></tr>
<tr><td>Text</td><td>Text</td></tr>
<tr><td>Text</td><td>Text</td></tr>
</table>
<script>
var table = document.getElementById("maximizableTable");
var maximized = false;
function maximizeorMinimize(elem){
  if(!maximized){
 table.style.width = "100%";
  table.style.height = "100%";
  table.style.top = "20%";
  table.style.left = "0";
  table.style.fontSize = "2em";
  elem.style.marginLeft = "60%";
  elem.src = "data:image/png;base64,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";
  elem.width = "50";
  elem.height = "50";
  elem.title = "Minimize";
  maximized = true;
  } else {
  table.style.width = "";
  table.style.height = "";
  table.style.top = "";
  table.style.left = "";
  table.style.fontSize = "";
  elem.style.marginLeft = "55%";
  elem.title="Maximize";
  elem.width = "15";
  elem.height = "15";
  elem.src = "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/mixed-vol-7/74/Untitled-1-11-08-07-17-512.png";
  maximized = false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help and comment - I implemented and added your snippet. I believe it doesn't go full screen. `https://ibb.co/bFvGG8` `https://ibb.co/hR4nOo` so imagine if there are other elements it should ignore or overlay them. I even added `position: fixed: and top:0px and left: 0px to it` the problem is when I use fixed position to enforce it to be at top then I lose the rest if the table - I might try `overflow: none`. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Just create a CSS style for `table.maximized` that has your font-size, height, width etc. and toggle that class on and off on the `<table>` element when the `img` is clicked.

Comment: @StephenP you are right it's cleaner ☺️ 

Comment: @JamieJamier Show me your code and I will try to help.

Comment: @hev cheers :) - `http://collabedit.com/r3x42` I believe you should be able to join within the link where I have the code - and we can do hotfix or chat there